# Apache2 Not Running Custom PHP App After Uploading to /var/www/html folder

Tags: ubuntu, php, apache2

I am installing a software that I bought. It's in PHP. So, I got a DigitalOcean server(ubuntu 22.04). Installed Apache2 and PHP 8.1.

Now, when I upload files to /var/www/html folder, it does nothing even though it has the index.php files.

After a bit of research, I found out it was permission issue. So, I ran these commands.

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html
chmod -R g+rwX /var/www/html
```

After this, now, index.php works. it even redirects to installer, but the page says Not Found.

[image]

I tried running this software locally using XAMPP and it works. But it's not runnong when I upload it to VPS. What should I do to make it work?

Thanks.

Comment: Does the directory `install` exist? If yes, try if it works if you add a trailing `/` in the URL. If not, there may be a .htaccess file missing.

Comment: `software that I bought` - if you bought it you are entitled to support. Use it.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you missed copying the hidden `.htaccess` file to the server, that contains the rewrite rules for your application.